# Azure data factory: MySQL access using pem file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to develop a pipeline in ADFv2 which connects with the MySQL DB and replicates a table daily.

For that I have the hostname, username and password but I am not sure where to put the pem key in the ADFv2 GUI when creating the linked service of MySQL.